# Substitution for HTML

Tags: html

Is there a programing language that can substitute HTML in making web sites.I don't mean something like ASP,JSP,PHP or similar.Specifically I am looking for a web site programing language which is not based on that line semantics.More specifficaly I' m looking for something that will add the WinForms Coordinates  possibility(Positioning elements based on their X and Y axes).Excuse my English,if I made any error.
I hope you understod my question.

Comment: What are `line semantics`? What `WinFroms` Coordinates and what do they have to do with websites?

Comment: Windows forms.Excuse my mistake.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't.

However, CSS has absolute positioning that will probably allow you to achieve what you want.

CSS

```
#box { position: absolute; left: 20px; top: 80px }
```

HTML

```
<div id="box"> I am absolutely positioned! </div>
```

Be advised though that it's often the wrong choice. HTML is fundamentally different from forms based systems, as it's designed to be displayed on a wide choice of different devices.

Maybe show what issue you're dealing with exactly, and ask about that specifically.

Comment: Nothing specifically.I just find HTML way too different to Windows programing and was just wondering if there was something more similiar to it.Something like c#.net or vb.net.Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Aleksandar Jovanov - it _is_ very different. Trying to make it the same will only get you in trouble. I suggest learning it from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't.

Web sites are written in HTML.

Most modern browsers understand a number of "languages", CSS, Javascript, XML, XSL and HTML.

Some also support SVG natively.

However it is entirely unclear what you want to.

Comment: Make web pages using the same technique I use to make c# forms.

Comment: @Aleksandar Jovanov - And what technique is that?

Answer (score 1):

If all you're looking for is a way to specify the position of elements on a fixed coordinate grid, HTML/CSS support this.  You're looking for [absolute positioning](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#absolute-positioning).  Be aware, however, that it's not nearly as cut and dry as it is on, for example, WinForms.  Browsers differ, you have little control over the display, etc.  It's do-able, but it has a different set of challenges than WinForms does.

Answer (score 0):

Well there's Flash, Java, Silverlight...

Comment: Yes,but I meant making web pages without all that rich content.Just a plain web page where I could position a button(for example) at 500,500 and a label at 200,200 without using tables.

Comment: Then the answer to your exact question is no, but see other post about absolute positioning in CSS!

Answer (score 0):

You could try Flash:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash.html

You would need html to embed the object, but the plugin space it provides does not use HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Your options are:

- HTML5
- HTML4 (or less)
- Flash
- Silverlight
- Java (applets)

So while, yes, you do have some options... no, you don't really.

Btw, who ever said that you can't do element/control positioning (a la X,Y coordinates) within HTML?  You absolutely can, and it's typically done with CSS and/or JavaScript.